# Forking Joomla! 1.5

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, open-source, acl

We have planned to fork Joomla! 1.5 with the name STRELIN. As Joomla is moving to 1.6, we would like to add new features without breaking the compatibility, with the new name Strelin. Of course that will be free and GPL. A simpler, better ACL (we are trying to make it simpler than Joomla 1.6 ACL) is the first one.

Can there be any issues? legal, copyright etc.? thoughts? Any help/ideas will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal or licensing issues, rather than a specific programming question.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can do anything you like as long as you respect GPL.

The Joomla artwork will be copyrighted unless stated otherwise so you'll probably need to strip out the presentation layer and replace it with your own.

Joomla was originally forked from Mambo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, we do respect GPL. We will also have a new default template for Strelin. By the way, as far as we know Joomla is completely GPL. Therefore, there should be no problem in forking/using their presentation layer (template) too. Thanks again.